# Is there a way to encrypt the excel file before sending out?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for help to automate the encrypting of the excel workbooks before emailing them out. Colleague wrote the script previously but have already left the job, as I have no knowledge in this, I'm seeking for help to see if anyone can point out where to insert the line of code to encrypt the excel files before they're attached to the draft email before I can send it out. Any pointers would be nice, thanks!

I have the code here

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_Attachment_2()
Working in 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:N" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 2    'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'If the unique value is a mail address create a mail
        If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'Copy the visible data in a new workbook
            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

            rng.Copy
            With NewWB.Sheets(1)
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .Cells(1).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Create a file name
            TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
            TempFileName = "(for info, pls) " & Ash.Parent.Name _
                         & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")

            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                'You use Excel 97-2003
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                'You use Excel 2007-2016
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If

            'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With NewWB
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName _
                      & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .SentOnBehalfOfNAme = "gunner@email.com"
                    .to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
                    .Subject = "[FOR INFO ONLY][" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy") & "]" & Space(1) & "<" & Range("E2").Value & ">"
                    .Attachments.Add NewWB.FullName
                    .Body = GetBoiler("C:\Users\Gunner\Desktop\bunny\bunny.txt")
                    .Display 'Or use .Sendcv
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Close savechanges:=False
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use password protection when you save the file. That will encrypt the file and only decrypt it when the correct password is provided.

```
    With NewWB
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName _
              & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, _
              Password:="yourpassword", _                                
              WriteResPassword:="yourreadonlypassword"
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SaveAs) for the SaveAs command.